# Importing existing git based projects into eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, xcode4

I have a number of projects using git for version control. Some are python modules others are C++ projects developed using Xcode4. However, I seemed to be struggling to import the project via git. I can easily import the actual source directories.

I tried doing the following:

1)I add my git repositories to the Egit repository browser.

2) Right click on the repository and click import project ...

3) Create the appropriate project

At this stage there is no source code in the project. I feel like I am missing a step somewhere.

Comment: What do you mean by "import". If the projects are already using git as a version control tool then surely they are already under version control? What do you think you need `git archive` for?

Comment: Apologies i used archive as a substitute for repository. I hope the question is clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse has a git plugin: http://eclipse.org/egit/

Just install EGit and import the actual source code directories. Then you can edit the source code in Eclipse, and use the Eclipse team provider interface to access version control facilities, and you're operating out of the same git repositories as you always were.